# return json.getString("key") returns null when I want get russian chars

Tags: java, php, json

Like this everyone is happy

.php

```
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["key"] = "Error database. The comment couldn't be added!";          
  die(json_encode($response));
```

.java

```
return json.getString("key");
```

But when i'm trying like this

```
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["key"] = "Russian - Русский!";          
  die(json_encode($response));
```

.java returns me null

```
Log.d("JSON GET STRING", json.getString("key"));//  NULL  ????
```

This Answer

```
json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // Like this..
```

would solve my problem if my mysql version was 5.4.0, But my mysql version lower and I need another way of solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` parameter inside the `json_encode()`

```
json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); // Like this..
```

Comment: It returns me an 02-27 08:19:31.320: E/JSON Parser(2050): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-27 08:19:31.380: W/System.err(2050): org.json.JSONException: No value for key

Comment: Cho'qqi soqol, boq bunga MySQL version is Версия MySQL-клиента: 5.1.71

Comment: @displayname The common language here is English, please, even if you write a comment to someone who you think will speak a different language common to both of you - use English. It will help future readers of the site to be able to understand your text.

Comment: @Angelo neuschitzer, ok I writed my MySQL version is 5.1.71, it is the reason my json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); didn't work for me.  JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for only MySQL version 5.4.0

Comment: @displayname I see. If you found the solution to your problem, please add an own answer to it. If you found that your question was missing information, please edit it to contain that information. We want to make this site, the questions and answers as useful for future readers as possible. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Angelo neushchitzer Thank you, nice of you

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for only MySQL version 5.4.0 -- Wrong; you meant **PHP 5.4**, not MySQL.